# I have some problems with cheking the status of a server

Tags: php, mysql, fsockopen

I am trying to make a script where I can chek the server status (Online/Offline) for servers like: Teamspeek, Minecraft and others.

I found this script:

```
<?php
    function getStatus($ip,$port){
           $socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, 3);
           if(!$socket) return "offline";
             else return "online";
        }
    echo getStatus("server.com", "80");
?>
```

But instead of having to change the sever name and port I wnat to get it from a mysql database.
So I've made this, but my problem is: I can't get the string connected to the script.
My Code to get the string looks like this:

```
<?php 
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "connect_mysql.php"; 
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
// Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product 
// details, if no then exit this script and give message why
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    // get all the product details
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id = $row["id"];
        $ip = $row["ip"];
        $port = $row["port"];
        $getit = $row["getit"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $content = $row["content"];
     }

} else {
    echo "That item does not exist.";
    exit();
}       
}
?>
```

So I thought I just could change the `echo getStatus("server.com", "80");` To `echo getStatus("$ip", "$port");` But that does not work.
Is there anyone that know what I have to do?

Comment: What's the value of `$ip` and `$port`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. Use mysqli_ instead of mysql.

Secondly, if you are limiting the result to 1, then you dont need while loop.

Now, when you get **id** in **get** method, you can check it in database and get details:

You will have to fire the function **getStatus()** once you get the details from database.

```
if ($productCount == 1){
   echo getStatus($row["ip"],$row["port"]);
} else {
         echo "That item does not exist.";
}
```